# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error on AJAX request to Neo4j database on localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax, neo4j

I am writing a plain JavaScrypt AJAX request, to connect from a MAMP server running on `localhost:8888` to a Neo4j database running on `localhost:7474`.

I am getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Following answers to similar questions, I have tried removing the requeste headers, such as...

```
// httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
```

... but this makes no difference. I have also looked into CORS, without discovering a solution.

What changes can I make to my JavaScript to get this to work? Is there a way for me to tell the Neo4j database server on my development machine to accept requests from the same machine?

My source code:

```
<button type="button">AJAX Request</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var httpRequest
  var restApiUrl = "http://neo4j:1234@localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit"

  document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    makeRequest(restApiUrl)
  }

  function makeRequest(url) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
      } 
      catch (e) {
        try {
          httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        } 
        catch (e) {}
      }
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance')
      return false
    }

    var parameters = JSON.stringify({
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "CREATE (n {props}) RETURN n",
    "parameters" : {
      "props" : {
        "name" : "My Node"
      }
    }
  } ]
})

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents
    httpRequest.open('POST', url, true)
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    httpRequest.send(parameters)
  }

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        console.log(httpRequest.responseText)
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.')
      }
    }
  }
})()
</script>
```

---

EDIT in response to @WilliamLyon

When I change the `makeRequest` method to use jQuery's `$.ajax` method (as shown below) I still get the same error, even when I use `contentType: "application/json"` or `dataType: 'json`.

```
function makeRequest(url) {
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    "statements" : [ {
      "statement" : "CREATE (n {props}) RETURN n",
      "parameters" : {
        "props" : {
          "name" : "My Node"
        }
      }
    } ]
  })

  $.ajax({
    url : url
  , type: "POST"
  , data : data
  , contentType: "application/json"
  , dataType: "json"
  , success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data, textStatus)
    }
  , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Try adding `contentType: 'application/json'` to the object you are passing to `$.ajax()`. Only JSON requests are wrapped in JSONP and I think it needs to be explicitly set.

Comment: or `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Still no joy. However, I have succeeded in creating a bare-bones [Node.js app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32957497/1927589) which allows me to isolate the query that is throwing an error, so I have a way to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

You are facing with [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue.

**What happens?**
Your browser is not permitted, by default, to access resources from other domains (for example - via AJAX). This one exists to make web more secure.

**Working solution**

Here is working solution (locally, on my machine):

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify({
      "statements" : [ {
        "statement" : "CREATE (n {props}) RETURN n",
        "parameters" : {
          "props" : {
            "name" : "My Node"
          }
        }
      } ]
    }),
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data, textStatus)
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    }
});
```

Notable things:

- **dataType** - this one sets that we accept JSON as response
- **contentType** - this one sets that we using JSON in request

I am using Neo4j **2.2.5** locally. This version sets "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in response, so there should be no problems. You can verify what your database in sending in response using Chrome devtools.

Example:

[image: devtools]

**Note:** see "Response headers" section.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error, because the port numbers are different.
Generally you can't make cross-domain Ajax calls if the server does not support it.
There are ways around it though.
You can use CORS or JSONP.

Comment: If you are using jQuery the `$.ajax()` method wraps JSON requests in JSONP automatically: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: As shown in the edited version of my question, I have tried using `$.ajax()`, but the error remains. It makes no difference whether I use `JSON.stringify()` or send the raw object.