# Unable to set node label dynamically using the Neo4j REST API

Tags: rest, neo4j

Following the syntax proposed on [the Neo4j REST API transactional page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-execute-multiple-statements), I have tried running the request `"CREATE (node:{group} { name: {name}}) RETURN node", { group: "Group", name: "Name"}`.

The use of `:{group}` as a dynamic variable causes an error:

> "Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax","message":"Invalid input '{': expected whitespace or a label name

Is this pilot error on my part, a bug in the Neo4j query parser, or a something that cannot be done?

Here's my Nodej.s code:

```
var request = require("request")
var host = 'localhost'
  , port = 7474
  , user = "neo4j"
  , pass = "1234"
var uri = 'http://' + user + ":" + pass + "@" + host + ':' + port + '/db/data/transaction/commit'

function runCypherQuery(query, params, callback) {
  request.post({
      uri: uri,
      json: {statements: [{statement: query, parameters: params}]}
    },
    function (err, res, body) {
      callback(err, body)
    })
}

runCypherQuery(
  "CREATE (node:{group} { name: {name}}) RETURN node"
, { group: "Group"
  , name: "Name"
  }
, function (err, resp) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(resp))
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: You can't parameterize node labels in Cypher. You'll have to build the string instead.

Comment: That's good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node Labels cannot be parameterized in Cypher.

Try updating the label in the query as a string instead of passing a parameter:

```
"CREATE (node:" + group + " {name: {name}}) RETURN node"
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Cypher does not support parameterized label names.